# How to fix deprecation warning for Chunk.modulesIterable?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I am the maintainer of [external-svg-sprite-loader](https://github.com/karify/external-svg-sprite-loader) and I noticed that when using it with webpack 5 I get the following warning:

```
[DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_MODULES_ITERABLE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modulesIterable: Use new ChunkGraph API
```

The build passes but I would like to able to fix this deprecation warning. However, I can't find any documentation about `modulesIterable` or the ChunkGraph API. Where should I look for it and what would be a potential solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue because I was using [compilation.hooks.optimizeChunks](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/#optimizechunks) to iterate through all modules in the compilation. After some research, I found that I could use [compilation.hooks.optimizeModules](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/#optimizemodules) to achieve the same result. Therefore, I switched to the latter and stopped getting the deprecation warning mentioned in my question. I would say that this is a better solution than iterating through the modules in a chunk since webpack seems to already be doing that internally anyway.

Comment: Care to share where you found this information? There doesn't appear to be much documentation available for the ChunkGraph API, yet.

Comment: No, there isn't much documention. AFAIK all there is available is this page: https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to iterate through modules in chunk, you could do it like this:

```js
compilation.chunks.forEach(chunk => {
  compilation.chunkGraph.getChunkModules(chunk).forEach((module) => {
    // module is available here
  })
});
```

You could find other useful methods of this class in its [source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/a16909c5fdb9efe9f1dd20226a1e7fc216160d1a/lib/ChunkGraph.js#L563). If you want to manipulate modules in chunk, probably it's better to use [ModuleGraph](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/a16909c5fdb9efe9f1dd20226a1e7fc216160d1a/lib/ModuleGraph.js#L65) class. For example:

```js
compilation.chunks.forEach(chunk => {
  compilation.chunkGraph.getChunkModules(chunk).forEach((module) => {
    const exportInfo = compilation.chunkGraph.moduleGraph.getExportInfo(module);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[external-svg-sprite-loader](https://github.com/karify/external-svg-sprite-loader/) is using `Chunk.modulesIterable` [(ref)](https://github.com/karify/external-svg-sprite-loader/blob/7631cca8eea9e62f3277ba029764887076c427b8/lib/SvgStorePlugin.js#L92) which is now deprecated and is being replaced with `ChunkGraph`

The package has a peer dependency of webpack^4.1.0 ([ref](https://github.com/karify/external-svg-sprite-loader/blob/7631cca8eea9e62f3277ba029764887076c427b8/package.json#L28)), so you can either downgrade your Webpack to 4.* to remove the warning or ask the package maintainer to add support for Webpack 5.

You can find the official deprecation note [here](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/)

Comment: sorry I guess I didn't explain myself correctly in my question. I am the package maintainer and would like to know how to fix this issue since I can't find any documentation for `ChunkGraph `.