# When trying to deploy NextJS app I get an error stating "Can't resolve 'pnpapi'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I can run `npm run build` locally, and it will create a local build of my NextJS app with no problems whatsoever... However, whenever I try and deploy it to Netlify, I get a weird error message which is
similar to a StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426589/how-to-fix-deprecation-warning-for-chunk-modulesiterable) and it was suggested that a version issue related to Webpack v4 and Webpack v5 was the reason why.

Since the default in NextJS 11.1.2 (the version I am using) is utilizing Webpack v5, I was able to utilize the Webpack v4 by following the next.config.js webpack configuration instructions they have their own website [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5)... and so this is how my next.config.js file looks so it runs using Webpack v4:

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  webpack5: false,
};
```

And this is the error I get with Webpack v4:

```
5:33:40 PM: $ npm run build
5:33:40 PM: > @minimal/minimal-kit-react@2.6.0 build
5:33:40 PM: > next build
5:33:41 PM: info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: webpack5 flag is set to false in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
5:33:41 PM: info  - Checking validity of types...
5:33:41 PM: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
5:35:50 PM: Failed to compile.
5:35:50 PM: 
5:35:50 PM: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pnpapi' in '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/ts-pnp'
5:35:50 PM: > Build error occurred
5:35:50 PM: Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
5:35:50 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:397:19
5:35:50 PM:     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
5:35:50 PM:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
5:35:50 PM:     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
5:35:50 PM:     at async Object.build [as default] (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:77:25)
5:35:50 PM: ​
5:35:50 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:35:50 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
5:35:50 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:35:50 PM: ​
5:35:50 PM:   Error message
5:35:50 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
5:35:50 PM: ​
5:35:50 PM:   Error location
5:35:50 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
5:35:50 PM:   npm run build
5:35:50 PM: ​
5:35:50 PM:   Resolved config
5:35:50 PM:   build:
5:35:50 PM:     command: npm run build
```

With that said, I've reverted my next.config.js file to simply be what it is always configured to in all my NextJS projects which is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
};
```

As a result, here is what I get with Webpack v5: Here is the error I receive from the failed Netlify deployment below, please let me know how else I can debug this... Thanks!

```
3:16:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:16:51 PM:   2. Build command from Netlify app                             
3:16:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:16:51 PM: ​
3:16:51 PM: $ npm run build
3:16:51 PM: > @minimal/minimal-kit-react@2.6.0 build
3:16:51 PM: > next build
3:16:53 PM: info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
3:16:53 PM: info  - Checking validity of types...
3:16:53 PM: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
3:19:40 PM: (node:1736) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_HAS_ENTRY_MODULE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.hasEntryModule: Use new ChunkGraph API
3:19:40 PM: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
3:19:40 PM: (node:1736) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_ADD_MODULE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.addModule: Use new ChunkGraph API
3:19:54 PM: Failed to compile.
3:19:54 PM: 
3:19:54 PM: ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/nft/LICENSE
3:19:54 PM: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
3:19:54 PM: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
3:19:54 PM: > Copyright 2019 Vercel, Inc.
3:19:54 PM: |
3:19:54 PM: | Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
3:19:54 PM: > Build error occurred
3:19:54 PM: Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
3:19:54 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:397:19
3:19:54 PM:     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
3:19:54 PM:     at async Object.build [as default] (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:77:25)
3:19:54 PM: ​
3:19:54 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:19:54 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
3:19:54 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:19:54 PM: ​
3:19:54 PM:   Error message
3:19:54 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
3:19:54 PM: ​
3:19:54 PM:   Error location
3:19:54 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
3:19:54 PM:   npm run build
3:19:54 PM: ​
3:19:54 PM:   Resolved config
```

**The error I get with Webpack v4 is more detailed, the error from Webpack v5 seems more obscure, however I do not know what is meant by pnpapi** ***I am not even utilizing the api folder from within NextJS pages...***